# delete and object that doesnt have a path(resource) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

i am new to rails so bare with my explanation.

I have a model, 'Exhibition photos', that doesn't have it's own controller as it belongs to a parent model called 'Galleries'. I want to delete an instance of the Exhibition photo model, how do i do it?

i currently have the error

```
 undefined method `exhibition_image_path'
```

i understand why, becuase it doesnt have a resource ( i think?)

gallery_controller.rb

```
        def update
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    @image = @gallery.exhibition_images.new

  end

  def destroy
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    @exhibition_image = @gallery.exhibition_images.find params[:id]
    @exhibition_image.destroy
    redirect_to '/guides'
  end

  def index
    @gallery = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
  end

  private 
  def gallery_params
   params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, exhibition_images_attributes: [:image])
 end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @gallery.exhibition_images.each do |exhibition_image| %>
    <%= image_tag exhibition_image.image(:guide) %>
    <% if current_admin %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", exhibition_image, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Confirm' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
    belongs_to :guide
  has_many :exhibition_images, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exhibition_images
```

exhibition_images.rb

```
class ExhibitionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gallery, :autosave => true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", guide: "500x500" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def destroy
  @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
  @exhibition_image = @gallery.exhibition_images.find params[:id]
  @exhibition_image.destroy
  redirect_to '/guides'
end

# And in your view
<%= link_to "Delete", exhibition_image, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Confirm' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

A few things. This destroy method is very broken, because you're trying to find both a `Gallery` and a `ExhibitionImage` using the same id. I like that you're searching for the image using `@gallery.exhibition_images.find` though, a lot of new users would just try to find using `GalleryExhibition.find`.

You mention at the top that you don't have a separate controller for your images. I think you should. So if you have a specific reason not to, let me know. But here's what I'd do:

`rails g controller exhibition_images`

Add it to your routes inside the gallery resource:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :galleries do
  resources :exhibition_images
end
```

With this in place, run `rake routes | grep exhibition_image` to see all these routes. You should see something that looks kind of like this:

```
gallery_exhibition_image GET    /galleries/:gallery_id/exhibition_images/:id(.:format) exhibition_images#show
                         PATCH  /galleries/:gallery_id/exhibition_images/:id(.:format) exhibition_images#update
                         PUT    /galleries/:gallery_id/exhibition_images/:id(.:format) exhibition_images#update
                         DELETE /galleries/:gallery_id/exhibition_images/:id(.:format) exhibition_images#destroy
```

Now what you can do is link to `ExhibitionImagesController#destroy` like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', gallery_exhibition_image_path(@exhibition, exhibition_image), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Really?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

If you hover over the link you'll see it linking to `/galleries/1/exhibition_images/3` (for example, if you're on Gallery 1 and image 3). Now your controller method would look them up:

```
# exhibitions_controller.rb
def destroy
  @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find(params[:gallery_id])
  @image = @gallery.exhibition_images.find(params[:id])
  @image.destroy
  redirect_to '/guides'
end
```

The key difference here is that we're looking up the `Gallery` model using `params[:gallery_id]` now, and the `ExhibitionImage` using `params[:id]`.

Comment: that is a fantastic, informative response. Thank you so much dude. Massive help.